# Simplifying binomial series

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

I am stuck with a series that I want to simplify-

$${2n+1\choose 0} + {2n+1\choose 1} + {2n+1\choose 2} + \dots +{2n+1\choose n}$$

I think somehow the result $${n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + {n\choose 2} + \dots + {n\choose n} = 2^n$$ has to be used.

I can't wrap my head around how the above series can be manipulated to get the required series.

Comment: **Hint:**  If instead of stopping at $n$ you went and continued, how would that be?  That is... consider $\binom{2n+1}{0}+\binom{2n+1}{1}+\binom{2n+1}{2}+\dots+\binom{2n+1}{2n}+\binom{2n+1}{2n+1}$.  How does that compare to your original series?  How does what is missing compare to your original series?

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Do you mean using n choose (k) = n choose (n-k)

Comment: That will be part of the punchline at the end, yes

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: My strategy for doing something like this is always to try writing the whole thing out with one or two small examples, like $2n+1=5$ and $2n+1=7$. Do that, and I’m sure there no longer be any mystery.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that next time for sure!

Comment: In line with the comment of @Lubin, and often for combinatorics problems in general, visualization is facilitated by [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the fact that $\binom{2n+1}{j} = \binom{2n}{j}+\binom{2n}{j-1}$ After rewriting your series in this way we get $$\binom{2n+1}{0} + \binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{1} + \binom{2n}{1} + \ldots+ \binom{2n}{n-1} + \binom{2n}{n-1} + \binom{2n}{n}$$
Also that's true that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$ and $\binom{2n+1}{0} = \binom{2n}{0}$, so we can rewrite this as
$$\binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{2n} + \binom{2n}{1} + \binom{2n}{2n-1} + \ldots +\binom{2n}{n+1} + \binom{2n}{n-1} + \binom{2n}{n}$$
And we see that it's the following series:
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{j} = 2^{2n}$$